# how to retrieve all the custom objects using Userid in quickblox ios

Tags: ios, quickblox, custom-object

can anyone tell the way for retrieving all the custom objects created by the user using user id.Now when i am retrieving, i am getting all the records irrespective of who created.

Can anyone suggest me how to retrieve using userId.

Answer (score 1):

You should use method

```
+ (QB_NONNULL QBRequest *)objectsWithClassName:(QB_NONNULL NSString *)className
                           extendedRequest:(QB_NULLABLE NSMutableDictionary QB_GENERIC(NSString *, NSString *) *)extendedRequest
                              successBlock:(QB_NULLABLE void (^)(QBResponse *QB_NONNULL_S response, NSArray QB_GENERIC(QBCOCustomObject *) *QB_NULLABLE_S objects, QBResponsePage *QB_NULLABLE_S page))successBlock
                                errorBlock:(QB_NULLABLE QBRequestErrorBlock)errorBlock;
```

with extendedRequest like:

```
NSMutableDictionary *extendedRequest = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[requestParameters setObject:@([QBSession currentSession].currentUser.ID) forKey:@"user_id"];
```

For custom user you should set ID of this user.